# Does a warlock have to use Hex Warrior every day?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, eldritch-invocations, hexblade

My warlock player and I are unsure about the rules of the Hexblade Warrior.

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch one weapon that you are proficient with and that lacks the two-handed property. [...] If you later gain the Pact of the Blade feature, this benefit extends to every pact weapon you conjure with that feature, no matter the weapon’s type.

Does this imply that you have to specify each morning which weapon you choose, even if said weapon is consistent?

And what about the 'Pact of the Blade' weapon do you just have to choose one weapon to create that day day, and you only get the bonus on that specific weapon until you go to bed?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "even if said weapon is consistent" a little bit further?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose: I'm guessing OP means "even if it's the same weapon each time".

Comment: Well, the Warlock in question has a shortsword, and he's planning to mainly use that weapon. Does he have to specify every day "I'm going to do my Hexblade Warrior ritual', or is it more that we assume he does it unless he specifies anything else? 

I guess it's up to the DM but I just want to know what seems more logical now.

Comment: @V2Blast: That was my guess as well, but I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: That is correct!

Answer (score 22):

## Hex Warrior on a normal weapon

Yes, the player must use this ability after every long rest if you want to keep using the benefits.

As a DM, you can allow the player to just do it every day without them having to tell you each time. Tell them that you will simply assume they do it with that particular weapon every day unless they tell you otherwise. There is no reason to add extra tedium to resting.

## Hex Warrior with a pact weapon

> If you later gain the Pact of the Blade feature, this benefit extends to **every pact weapon you conjure** with that feature, no matter the weapon’s type.

With a pact weapon, the warlock automatically gets the benefit of Hex Warrior with every weapon they conjure with Pact of the Blade. It doesn't matter what type or how often it changes, they just get it.

It is also worth noting that you can even apply Hex Warrior to a normal weapon and a pact weapon at the same time, as clarified by [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/930235396792786944):

> The Hex Warrior feature is intentionally worded to extend its benefit to two potential weapons: the weapon you touch and a pact weapon you conjure.

Comment: Also, by my reading, the Hex Warrior could use this on a single normal weapon as well as his pact weapon. Extending the benefit to his pact weapons as well is a little ambiguous, but I read it as completely extra and allowing for TWF.

Comment: @NickBrown: Good point. I have added an addendum in to make that clear.

Comment: Fantastic. I didn't know there was support from Jeremy Crawford on my interpretation. I'm traveling, so searching is not so easy. Adding that clarification plus the tweet makes this even better.